# MongoEngine throws exception TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object

Tags: python, regex, mongoengine, deep-copy

I am getting  the  exception on querying mongodb model (Python/MongoEngine) with list and regex query. The code  is

```
from mongoengine import *
import re 

db = connect('testdb')

class Team(Document):
    name = StringField()
    groups = ListField(ReferenceField('Group'))

class Group(Document):
    name = StringField()

Team.drop_collection()
Group.drop_collection()

g1 = Group('G1')
g1.save()

g2 = Group('G2')
g2.save()

g3 = Group('G3')
g3.save()

g4 = Group('G4')
g4.save()

t = Team('Team1',[g1,g2,g3])
t.save()

t = Team('Team2',[g1,g2,g4])
t.save()

t = Team('Team3',[])
t.save()

t = Team('Team3',[g3,g2])
t.save()

t = Team('Team3',[g4,g1])
t.save()


# TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object
teams = Team.objects( Q(groups__in=[g3,g2]) & Q(name=re.compile('eam3')))
for team in teams:
   print team.name  


#-------------------------
```

The exception traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_mongoengine_query.py", line 46, in <module>
    for team in teams:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 81, in _iter_results
    self._populate_cache()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 93, in _populate_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self.next())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1137, in next
    raw_doc = self._cursor.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1182, in _cursor
    self._cursor_obj = self._collection.find(self._query,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1215, in _query
    self._mongo_query = self._query_obj.to_query(self._document)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 91, in to_query
    query = self.accept(SimplificationVisitor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 141, in accept
    return visitor.visit_combination(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 41, in visit_combination
    return Q(**self._query_conjunction(queries))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/visitor.py", line 61, in _query_conjunction
    combined_query.update(copy.deepcopy(query))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 257, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object
```

Update-1:  The following code generates same exception

```
query = ( Q(groups__in=[g3,g2]) & Q(name=re.compile('eam3')))
copy.deepcopy(query)
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the deepcopy of compiled regex pattern is not supported in Python([since Python 2.5](http://bugs.python.org/issue10076)), i.e.,

```
copy.deepcopy(re.compile('eam3'))
```

is not supported. mongoengine will use copy.deepcopy when combine multiple query objects. So if you use a single regex filter, the query is OK with mongoengine, but not multiples.

mongoengine support a set of string queries, you may find them [in the document](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/querying.html#string-queries).

Answer (score 1):

Using mongoengine==0.22.1 I had a query like this:

```
regex = re.compile(".*v3\.[0-9]{1,4}/transaction/[0-9a-fA-F]*$")
from_date = kwargs.get("from_date", "2000-01-01")
to_date = kwargs.get("to_date", (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

qs = (
    ApiLog.objects.filter(
        time_stamp__gte=parse(from_date),
        time_stamp__lt=parse(to_date) + timedelta(days=1),
    )
    .filter(url=regex)
    .only("id", "url") 
    .order_by("time_stamp")
)
```

This query yielded the dreaded

```
  "TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object"
```

when I tried to paginate the results.

Upgrading from python 3.6.12 to 3.7.9 fixed the problem for me.

I am not sure why this error even occurred nor if it's origin is the same as what the OP shared but since this page came up on a google search for this error, I thought I'd post this here.